# Did The Cybermen influence the creation of The Borg?

Tags: star-trek, doctor-who, borg, inspiration, cybermen

Did Doctor Who's **Cybermen** influence Star Trek writers when they created the **Borg**? Did they even copy the idea?

There are many similarities: both are cyborgs, both assimilate other species by force, changing them into their own kind, etc.

**Update:** based on the comments below, I would like to add that I am only interested in referenced facts, not speculation.

Comment: I always thought the Borg were inspired by Marvel's Technarchy.

Comment: They are basically what became the Phalanx. They were interoduced in 1984 which was a few years before TNG and the introduction to the Borg.

Comment: @neilfein: thanks for explaining the downvote. For the record, I'm not looking for speculation but referenced answers e.g. by the writer of **[Q Who](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_Who)** saying that he was influenced by the Cybermen. Hmmm, now I think about it, **that title is a bit of a clue**, eh? (Now that *is* inviting speculation... :) )

Comment: I read somewhere that the Borg were loosly based on the Cybermen as a homage to Doctor Who, the production team didn't realize how iconic the Cybermen were though

Comment: it was some time ago, I sure it was a referance book, possibly an old Star Trek Encylopedia it shouldn't be hard to fined as it dose crop up now and then

Comment: You could even make an argument that the Borg were inspired by Cold War-era Soviet Communism, at least unconsciously.

Comment: Strongly related:  The Borg [were originally planned to be insectoid, not cybernetic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22959/2242).  This doesn't, however, answer the question, as in theory their redesign could have been influenced by the Cybermen.

Comment: Incidentally you might be interested in [Assimilation²](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Assimilation%C2%B2_%28comic_story%29)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While Science Fiction writers tend to borrow and be inspired by other franchises and concepts in a very loose sense, the Borg are not directly based on the Cybermen.

As mentioned in *[Star Trek: The Next Generation: The Continuing Mission](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_The_Next_Generation_-_The_Continuing_Mission)*, the original concept for the Borg was the character Lord Dread from [*Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future). Like the Borg, Lord Dread was a cybernetic being bent on assimilation and domination, and [spoke and moved very deliberately](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19aaAE9OFbY).

- [Related promo for *Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tXJpzfkscE&feature=related), featuring more of Lord Dread

Comment: This makes for a wonderful connection between SF everywhere.  B5 writer Joe Straczynski was Captain Power's most prolific writer (the show contains the first on-screen mention of a "Babylon 5" colony), along with producer (and later B5 writer) Larry DiTillio.

Comment: Oh wow. He looks just like a Borg (err the other way around).

Answer (score 8):

The Cybermen used the phase "resistance is futile" in *Tomb of the Cybermen* which aired in September 1967. Second Doctor (Patrick Throughton).  No doubt it was seen by one of the writer or creators of Star Trek.

Answer (score 7):

I have always belived the thought of The Borg was spun around the first Star trek movie: Star Trek: The Motion Picture from 1979 where Decker suggested that they strike at V'GER then run. And Spock says "Run to where? Resistance would be futlie".
Even when you see the movie, the rectangled shapes is there, the way it asimilated all around it, and even the way it never wanted to do anything else than programmed for, and even the fear the humans have for it to reach Earth are the same.

So, no, I dont think the writers copyed the Cybermen, they took a proven Star Trek plot from the first movie and twisted it.

Comment: +1 I had always assumed the Borg were derived from that first movie, as well.

Comment: The Cybermen predate ST: TMP by thirteen years (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tenth_Planet), but I think your point still stands.

Comment: Some of the writers for ST:TNG (Ron Moore, for example) were not fans of earlier iterations of Trek and essentially knew the story lines as little more than reference points so they didn't duplicate them, so without comments from the writers, oblique connections are not always a sign the writers intended those connections.

Comment: Another point (two comments, to keep points separate): Several stories from _Star Trek: Phase II_ were used in ST:TNG, one became "The Child" and another become "Devil's Due."  But other ideas were taken from the leftover scripts from that aborted series for ST:TNG, and one script did include an alien species similar to the Borg.  But even then, that was in the 1970s, which would still be after the Cybermen.

Comment: The connection was retconned in later. It was not their original intent for the two to be the same.

Comment: The concept that the Borg are related to V'Ger is based on a joke by Gene Roddenberry and is not canon. It was only fleshed out in the (again, non-canon) book *[The Return](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Return)*, written well after "Q Who?".

Answer (score 2):

I feel that the Cybermen did influence the creation of the Borg, at least a little. My evidence for this stems from the 1967 Doctor Who "Tomb of the Cybermen." In episode 3, the newly revived Cybermen use the direct quote "resistance is futile" in reference to them trying to convert the Doctor and his party into Cybermen (i.e. assimilation). Those two linked concepts, which together make up two key aspects of the Borg, are too similar to ignore.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately for your theory, not only did the phrase "resistance is futile" pre-date Tomb of the Cybermen *in Doctor Who* by a couple years (an entirely un-Cybermen-like alien with Borg-like ambitions in The Web Planet says it first), the phrase didn't originate in the show at all; it was supposedly used by Nazi Germany, and prior to *that* it was used in a 1930s short story. [The Wiki article has some details.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_(Star_Trek)#.22Resistance_is_futile.22) While the Cybermen may have inspired the Borg, they're not the concepts' basal origin.