# What species were the aliens in ‘Conspiracy’?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, season 1 episode 25, 'Conspiracy', there were aliens

> who are an insect-like parasite that controls the body of whomever it enters.

What species was this alien?

> Also, was the alien related to the creatures from Ceti Alpha, used by Kahn to control Chexkov and Captain Terell?

Comment: Not a duplicate. Here, the question is what their name is. In http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22956/why-was-the-alien-threat-in-the-next-generation-episode-conspiracy-never-follo the question is about plot and production.

Answer (score 7):

They never appear again or recieve an official name in Star Trek canon.

---

In noncanoncial sources sources, however, they are named **Bluegills** or are simply called **Parasites** and are closely related to (and in some sources, genetically engineered from) **Trill Symbionts** (and therefore *not* related to the Ceti Alpha V creature, as long as we assume that it was truly indigenous to the planet as Khan claimed).

So the answer to your question really depends on which books you read.

[Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Neural_parasite_(24th_century)#Apocrypha)

[Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22956/12857)