# What are the similarities between The Borg and The Cybermen?

Tags: star-trek, doctor-who, borg, cybermen

Having watched very little Star Trek, when I heard the monologue of:

> We are the Borg. We shall add your technological and biological distinctions to our own.

It reminded me of the mantra of both the Mondasian and modern Cybermen in Doctor Who:

> You belong to us, you will become like us.

Aside from this ideology, are there any other similarities between the two races?

Comment: For starters: They're both races of cyborgs powerful enough to conquer planets. They're both portrayed as utterly lacking any human-like emotions. Their primary goal seems to be assimilating/upgrading other species. They both became famous recurring villains in their respective franchises.

Comment: Related: [Did The Cybermen influence the creation of The Borg?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6128/143)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the surface, they are the same.  They are cyborgs, they conquer and assimilate the conquered.  When separated from the "collective" their organic brains tend to assert themselves.

There is a certain sameness to the cybermen though. When assimilated, its really just a brain driving a cyber body, and most all of the cyber bodies are interchangeable.  With the Borg, they grow and adapt and are enhanced when new technology and races are assimilated.  Cybermen can't be un-cybered either, whereas it has been shown that some Borg can be un-Borged.

Comment: Can you provide any sources for your answer? It is recommended that you support your answer with as much evidence to show proof your answer is valid and not just an assumption you've made.